# How to apply triming in beforevalidate method in cakephp appmodel

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I use cakephp framework ,in that i post parent and child model data but i want to remove triming from that. My demo code is

```
Array
(
    [Currency] => Array
        (
            [Code] =>         fgfg
            [Name] => fg
            [Description] => 
            [NoOfDecimalPrecision] => 3
            [CurrencyName] => bnjmhj
            [CurrencySymbol] => hjh
            [DecimalPrecisionName] => bjmh
            [DecimalPrecisionSymbol] => 
            [CurrencyScaleType_058] => 368
            [IsPrefixSymbol] => 0
            [IsInActive] => 0
            [IsExchangeCurrency] => 0
            [RevisionNumber] => 
        )

    [CurrencyDenomination] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LineNo] => 1
                    [RowState] => 435
                    [DenominationName] =>          jhgjk
                    [DenominationDetails] => kgk
                    [DenominationValue] => 1
                    [RevisionNumber] => 1
                    [DenominationSequence] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

In my code currency is parent model and currencydenimination in child model so i want in both case.my data post dyanamic not static.so please suggest solution.

Comment: what is triming? What exactly do you want to achieve? What did you try so far?

Comment: I do trimming upon POST via Component: [see trimDeep()](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Controller/Component/CommonComponent.php#L41)

Comment: How to use deeptrim in beforevalidated appmodel??

Comment: Components are for controllers, not models.